# How to choose Database in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image: My database]

I have a default database, but I need to connect to the second database, how I can do it in Android
I am using Firebase Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution,
We should copy the URL of database
[image: Example]

And paste it into getInstance method

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(DATABASE_URL).//something
```